# Degrees of freedom of a constrained vector

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

I have to handle with this lagrangian of a real vector $\chi^\mu$

$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^2 + B^\mu \square \chi_\mu + C\, \partial_\mu \chi^\mu + \mathcal{L}_{int}
$$

where $B^\mu$ and $C$ are Lagrange multipliers and $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the field strength of $\chi^\mu$.
Here $\mathcal{L}_{int}$ includes all the interactions that are constructed according to the symmetry

$$
\chi^\mu \rightarrow\chi^\mu +\xi^\mu
$$

where $\partial_\mu \xi^\mu=\square\xi^\mu=0$.

Let's turn off all the couplings controlling the interactions and just focus on the quadratic part of the action.

**Question:** I have the feeling this theory is sick or ill-defined. How many degrees of freedom are actually propagating? How does the answer change if we turn on the interactions?

**---EDIT after answer----**

My confusion might be clearer by discussing the problem in the path-integral formalism. The partition function is

$$\begin{align}
Z[0] &= \int \mathcal{D\,}B^\mu \mathcal{D}\,C\, \mathcal{D}\,\chi^\mu e^{i\int d^d x  -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^2 + B^\mu \square \chi_\mu + C\, \partial_\mu \chi^\mu + \mathcal{L}_{int}} \cr &\propto \int \mathcal{D}\,\chi^\mu e^{i\int d^d x  -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}^2 + \mathcal{L}_{int}}\delta\left(\square\chi_\mu\right)\delta\left(\partial^\mu\chi_\mu\right) \cr &= \int \mathcal{D}\,\chi^\mu e^{i\int d^d x \mathcal{L}_{int}}
\end{align}$$

where I performed the integration over the Lagrange multipliers. It looks the kinetic term is not there.

Comment: Why do the delta functions vanish the $F^2$ term? What I see is that they are putting the lagrangian on-shell (because they are equivalent to the eoms).

Comment: I am assuming there are no asymptotic field-configurations such that the kinetic term is equal to $F_{\mu\nu}^2 = -2(\chi_\mu \square \chi^\mu + (\partial_\mu \chi^\mu)^2)$ up to total derivatives

Comment: Where does this Lagrangian come from?

Comment: @Qmechanic just invented to solve a problem I am working on. I think the details are unimportant here. From the QFT side, I want to understand if a theory of a transverse and harmonic vector ($\partial_\mu \chi^\mu = \square \chi_\mu = 0$) is consistent or not. I just added the Lagrange multipliers to embed the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

1. For starters, OP's system is over-constrained: 4 gauge fields $\chi_{\mu}(x)$ is constrained by 4+1=5 Lagrange multiplier fields $B^{\mu}(x)$ and $C(x)$. This leads to an ill-defined product $$\prod_x\delta^4(\Box\chi_{\mu}(x))~\delta(\partial^{\nu}\chi_{\nu}(x))$$ of delta distributions in the path integral.
2. Put in a different way: There is another gauge symmetry
   $$ \delta \chi_{\mu}=0, \qquad \delta B^{\mu}~=~\partial^{\mu}\varepsilon,\qquad \delta C~=~\Box\varepsilon, $$
   which needs to be gauge-fixed. After that, there will be no propagating DOF.

Comment: Does it hold irrespectively of the interactions?

Comment: Assuming that the interactions $\mathcal{L}_{int}(\chi)$ does not depend on $B^{\mu}$ and $C$: Yes.

Comment: Can you make an example of interaction involving $B_\mu$ or $C$ which may lead to healthy propagating degrees of freedom? Maybe a linear interaction in $C$

Answer (score 0):

Just considering the free lagrangian.

If you compute the equations of motion (by using Euler-Lagrange formalism for higher-derivative lagrangians) you obtain the Maxwell's theory equation

$$ \partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=0.$$

Of course, the terms included by Lagrange multipliers are just constraints on $\chi_\mu$, so apart from the eoms, we have that

$$ \partial^\mu\chi_\mu=0.$$

This condition is fixing (partially) the gauge on $\chi_\mu$ (the so-called Lorentz condition).

The other constraint $\partial^2\chi_\mu$ is automatically satisfied from the previous ones:

$$\partial^\mu F_{\mu\nu} = \partial^2\chi_\nu- \partial_\nu (\partial^\mu\chi_\mu)=\partial^2\chi_\nu=0,$$

so I would say that the (free) lagrangian is just the Maxwell lagrangian written in a particular gauge. The answer to the question would be: there are **2 physical degrees of freedom propagating** (in 4d) as in the Maxwell theory.

With respect to the interacting lagrangian, I do not have an answer.

Comment: thanks. This is also what I thought. However, I am confused because the Lagrange multipliers imply constraints on the field. I edited my question